# FAILED: meson-install

Tags: gnome, meson-build

I want to install the totem app from the source GNOME code.

I cloned source code for totem app from GNOME github, and compiled with messon and ninja commands, and all of that was successfully compiled.

The problem is when I call command meson install, at one point it breaks off.

The steps I followed:

```
git clone https://github.com/GNOME/totem.git
cd totem
meson builddir
ninja
ninja test
cd ..
meson compile
cd builddir
sudo ninja install
```

Error which occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/meson", line 20, in <module>
    sys.exit(mesonmain.main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/mesonmain.py", line 226, in main
    return run(sys.argv[1:], launcher)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/mesonmain.py", line 215, in run
    return run_script_command(args[1], args[2:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/mesonmain.py", line 163, in run_script_command
    return module.run(script_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/scripts/yelphelper.py", line 130, in run
    merge_translations(build_subdir, abs_sources, langs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/scripts/yelphelper.py", line 57, in merge_translations
    subprocess.call([
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'itstool'
FAILED: meson-install 
/usr/bin/meson install --no-rebuild
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Note: I tried on two PC (ubuntu 20.04), and on one PC it works, and other I got an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks you are missing one of the build dependencies for totem: [itstool](http://itstool.org/) (converts xml localization (language translations) data); dependent through usage of [i18 module](https://mesonbuild.com/i18n-module.html) [here](https://github.com/GNOME/totem/blob/master/meson.build#L208). You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install itstool
```

[Here](https://linuxfromscratch.ru/blfs/view/7.7/gnome/totem.html) is the list of other *required* dependencies (latest or another package versions may or may not work though).